# Monthly and Daily Count Dynamically

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this

```
id | visit_date          | location_name | group_id | visit_date_only
-------------------------------------------------------------
17 |2019-06-11 16:38:00..| Location 1    |     1    | 2019-06-11
24 |2019-06-05 12:20:00..| Location 2    |     1    | 2019-06-05
11 |2019-05-13 18:40:00..| Location 1    |     1    | 2019-05-13
```

I would like to create a monthly and daily counting.
Ex:

```
Month | count
-------------
June  |    2
```

AND

```
   Day     | count
--------------------
2019-06-11 |   1
```

I know about the count method and that you can put in the query something like
'from  to '

But, is there a way this can be dynamic without me having to put which month and which date, meaning the system detects which month we're in and what day we're in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use current_date.

Like

```
WHERE date_trunc('month', current_date) <= visit_date 
    AND visit_date < date_trunc('month', current_date) + INTERVAL '1 month'
```

Same idea with today, but use 'day' instead of 'month'

Comment: This worked like a charm, saved my life! thank you!